# Change tile at TileLayer at state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

My question is how to change url of tile map in that case:

```
function ChangeView({ center, zoom }) {
    const map = useMap();
    map.setView(center, zoom);
    return null;
}   

function TrackerMap({ darkMode, countries, casesType, center, zoom}) {

    const currentTheme = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const mapTheme = darkMode ? `https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png` : `https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`;

    return (
        <MapWrapper currentTheme={currentTheme}>
            <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom}>
                <ChangeView center={center} zoom={zoom} />  
                <TileLayer 
                    url={mapTheme}
                />
            </MapContainer>
        </MapWrapper>
    )
}
```

I would like to toggle TileLayer style in relation with `darkMode` props value. But in that implementation the new values at `darkMode` proprs dont trigger a changes at `<TileLayer />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official [docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components)

> Child components in React Leaflet use their props as options when creating the corresponding Leaflet instance, as described in Leaflet's documentation.
>
> By default these props should be treated as immutable, only the props
> explicitely documented as mutable in this page will affect the Leaflet
> element when changed.

Therefore you will need an extra component which will toggle the map basemap tilelayer using `map.addLayer()` and you will not need to use react-leaflet's TileLayer but you will build your own. You can further adjust it to your requirements.

```
function TileLayer({ darkMode }) {
  const map = useMap();
  var dark = L.tileLayer(
    "https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  );
  const normal = L.tileLayer(
    "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  );
  map.addLayer(darkMode ? dark : normal);

  return null;
}
```

import it as a child of MapContainer

```
<MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
      <ChangeView center={center} zoom={zoom} />
      <TileLayer darkMode={darkMode} />
 </MapContainer>
```

Now on the component where you use `TrackerMap` create a state variable to hold the darkMode status and use for instance a button to toggle the darkMode status.

```
const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(false);

<>
  <button onClick={() => setIsDark((prevState) => !prevState)}>
        Change basemap
  </button>
  <TrackerMap center={position} zoom={12} darkMode={isDark} />
</>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-tile-at-tilelayer-at-state-change-in-react-leaflet-v3x-5wr9e)