# How do I programatically a layer in react-leaflet?

Tags: typescript, react-leaflet-v3

I'm using react-leaflet (3.2.0) and TypeScript,
In my project, I don't want switch layers with LayersControl, but I need do it programatically. So I have something like this:

```
export const getDefaultBgLayer = () => ( 
       <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a 
                  href="osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' 
                  url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" maxZoom={20} 
                  minZoom={3} />
 );
    
 const MyMap = () => {
    
        const [bgLayer, setBgLayer] = useState<any>(getDefaultBgLayer());
    
        return (
                <MapContainer>
    
                    {bgLayer}
    
                </MapContainer>
        );
    
    }

export default MyMap;
```

and If I'm trying

```
setBgLayer(getAnotherBgLayer())
```

It not will change a backgroud layer. Btw. getAnotherBgLayer return correct backgroud layer becouse:

```
const [bgLayer, setBgLayer] = useState<any>(getAnotherBgLayer());
```

works correctly.
Any one can help?
Regards, Mik

Comment: If you return a string this is not how this library works. What exactly `getDefaultBgLayer` returns?

Comment: export const getDefaultBgLayer = () => (
    <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        maxZoom={20} minZoom={3}
    />);

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65965521/change-tile-at-tilelayer-at-state-change/65966026#65966026).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone who tried to help me.

I have solved it on this way:

```
    setBgLayer(undefined)
    setTimeout(() =>
        setBgLayer(mapsource)
    , 0)
```

Regards,
M.